# Place object in GPS coordinates ar foundation unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gps, arkit, arcore

I want to instantiate an object in some specific coordinates in ARFundation,
I have tried several ways but none convinces me or gives me the result that I want,

- One is with a radius with which if you pass that radius you activate an object that is in your position and it already leaves it fixed but it does not convince me because you have to reach the exact point first to be able to visualize it and you already lose accuracy with the radius unless you put a radius of 2cm.
- The other, I got from this blog https://blog.anarks2.com/Geolocated-AR-In-Unity-ARFoundation/ but depending on which cardinal point you are looking at, it is instantiated in one place or another (I think I remember that it says that is unfinished)

Does anyone have a proven way since it works and has enough accuracy?

Comment: Good day! There are 3 ways how to do that : 1. Using this plugin, works like a charm - > https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/ar-gps-location-134882 2. Using Map Box, I will link some tutorial here - > https://www.instructables.com/Placing-AR-Objects-at-GPS-Coordinates-in-Augmented/ 3. Create you custom solution

Answer (score 2):

Apple has released something called `ARGeoAnchor`.

I think it is not yet supported on Unity though.

If you wish, you can use it, with RealityKit been your engine.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/argeoanchor

**Also, note it is only supported in distinct locations in the US.**

From what I could tell so far, it is very accurate, with the problem only been the altitude you wish to put things on.